# Prevent mouseover repeating over multiple hovers

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I created a link that when the user hover in it, some image will pop out, and when they hover out, the image will disappear. Everything is working perfectly fine, However, when they hover over the link multiple times the image will keep carrying on popping out until it is finished depending on how many times they hover the link. Is there any way to delay the execution of the hover event to prevent this from happening? My code is below

```
$('.my_link a').bind('mouseover', function () {
    var my_title = $(this).html();
    var title_width = parseInt($(this).width());
    var next = $(this).next();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/my_info_hover.php',
        data: {
            my_title: my_title
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        //Disable mouseover from this class?
        $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
        $(next).html(data).css('left', title_width + 10 + 'px');
    });

}).mouseout(function () {
    //Enable mouseover again?
    $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
});
```

Comment: What exaclty are you getting in that ajax function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer, $this;
    $('.my_link a').bind('mouseover', function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $this = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
           var anime_title = $this.html();
           var title_width = parseInt($this.width(), 10);
           var next = $this.next();

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax/my_info_hover.php',
                data: {
                    my_title: my_title
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                //Disable mouseover from this class?
                $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
                $(next).html(data).css('left', title_width + 10 + 'px');
           });
           console.log("This works!");
        }, 1000); //function fires after 1000ms = 1s
    }).mouseout(function () {
        //Enable mouseover again?
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('.my_info_wrap').remove();
    });
});
```

The [SetTimeout Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) waits a specific time and then executes the function in it. The clearTimeout clears the timer.
So everytime a user hovers over the link the timer begins, if he does it again the timer gets cleared and immediately begins new.
Of course the timer has to be cleared when a user leaves the link.
In the example above the function fires after 1s.

But I'd prefer [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of bind. Therefore you just need to replace bind with .on

```
$('.my_link a').on('mouseover', function () {
    ...
}).mouseout(function() {
    ...
});
```

**EDIT**

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xat54/4/) here
...and [another version](http://jsfiddle.net/Xat54/5/) with .on() instead of .bind()

Comment: My fault, I tried your code, but it gives me the same result. The image will keep carrying on popping out until it is finished depending on how many times they hover the link. And your fiddle is not working, i am using Chrome

Comment: Hmm my fiddle outputs "This works!" correctly if I hover over the link/div...if not there's no "This works!" in my console. In the fiddle I had to comment out your ajax call of course. Can you maybe set up your own fiddle to see whats going on?

Comment: Thanks! It works! I just had a little mistakes, but your code works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
var element = '#elementId';

var enter = function () {
 console.log('entered');
 $(element).stop().fadeIn('fast');
}

var leave = function () {
 console.log('left');
 $(element).stop().fadeOut('slow');
}

$('.toHoverOn').hover(function(){leave()}, function(){enter()});
```

Please note that you can replace the individual `leave` and `enter` functions and just just immedietely write your logic in the callbacks, that is:

```
  var element = '#elementId';

    $('.toHoverOn').hover(function(){
      console.log('entered');
      $(element).stop().fadeOut('slow');
    }, function(){
       console.log('left');
       $(element).stop().fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

The first one would be more useful if there's a lot happening in your 'mouseenter/hover' and 'mouseleave' event.